# Can i use isset() to control execution of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I have created an editable database to help me automate weekly member updates. There are 9 values that each member updates each week, these are controlled by $_POST submit to secondary php.

From that php,  the post values are set as php var,  then used to UPDATE sql db.

```
mysql_select_db("web_footy1") or die(mysql_error());




// The SQL statement is built
$strSQL = "UPDATE Round_6 SET "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game1= '$Game1', ";

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game2= '$Game2', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game3= '$Game3', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game4= '$Game4', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game5= '$Game5', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game6= '$Game6', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game7= '$Game7', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game8= '$Game8', "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game9= '$Game9' "; 

$strSQL = $strSQL . "WHERE  Member = '$Member' "; 

// The SQL statement is executed 
mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Yes,  i am aware this is subject to SQL injection,  it is a private site so security can wait atm

The problem is that all values are update at same time, and to update one,  you need to re enter all otherwise they are replaced with empty value.

So my question in twofold. 
 A) What is the cleanest way to be able to control each variable separately, 
B) Can i, and if so, how to  use isset($GameX)  to control which queries are executed.

Eg

```
IF (isset($Game1)) {UPDATE Round6 SET Game1='$Game1' WHERE Member='$Member'} ;
```

Please keep in mind, 3 weeks ago i knew nothing about coding, and have crash coursed in html, php and sql in that time... Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *really really really* can't recommend enough that you **FIX** your SQL injection.

Having said that, you can programatically add conditions to your UPDATE clause.
An example might be the following snippet:

```
<?php

$Game3 = "things";
$Game5 = "stuff";
$Game6 = "awesome";
$Member = 'ben';

$update_parts = array();
for ($game_counter = 1; $game_counter < 10; $game_counter++) {
    $variable_name = "Game" . $game_counter;
    if ( isset($$variable_name) ) { // This is like isset($Game1)
        $update_parts[] = "Game" . $game_counter . " = '" . $$variable_name . "'";
    }
}

if ( sizeof($update_parts) > 0 ) {
    $strSQL = "UPDATE Round_6 SET ";
    $strSQL .= implode(", ", $update_parts);
    $strSQL .= " WHERE Member = '$Member'";
    echo $strSQL;
}
```

I've put in a couple of variables up the top there. This yields the following SQL:

```
UPDATE Round_6 SET Game3 = 'things', 
  Game5 = 'stuff', Game6 = 'awesome' WHERE Member = 'ben'
```

**EDIT**: If you want to use PDO, you need the Query and the Parameters separated. In my example below, I'm putting the Query parameters in

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","username","password"); // Your Connection String

$update_parts = array();
$query_params = array();
for ($game_counter = 1; $game_counter < 10; $game_counter++) {
    $variable_name = "Game" . $game_counter;
    if ( isset($$variable_name) ) { // This is like isset($Game1)
        $update_parts[] = "Game" . $game_counter . " = ?";
        $query_params[] = $$variable_name;
    }
}

if ( sizeof($update_parts) > 0 ) {
    $strSQL = "UPDATE Round_6 SET ";
    $strSQL .= implode(", ", $update_parts);
    $strSQL .= " WHERE Member = ?";
    $query_params[] = $Member;

    // Here is where you'd run the update
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($strSQL);
    $stmt->execute($query_params); // Notice I'm passing in the parameters separately
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that it would be better to have your game data in an array. That way, you can use `array_key_exists` which is much nicer and cleaner than variable variables (the `$$` syntax)

Comment: That looks like it is pretty much what i am after in terms of output...  Yiur suqqestion on sql injection fix would be to put it in PDO,  of which i am still trying to wrap my head around... Can you show an example of the above in pdo...  I have checked and mysql server  is v 5.5+

Comment: Excellent... Greatly appreciated

Comment: you got my vote just because your first line was "I really really really can't recommend enough that you FIX your SQL injection."

Comment: Ran code,  functionality is exactly same... Eg Game5="" is still entered into the db as null entry,  rather than omitted from the sql string altogether

Comment: OK. In that case, your `$Game5` variable IS defined, but is either NULL or blank or an empty string or something. So you'll want to change `if ( isset($$variable_name) )` to something more like

`if ( isset($$variable_name) && !is_null($$variable_name) && strlen(trim($$variable_name)) > 1 )`

Comment: Produces an error... Maybe looking at it wrong way... Can the trimming of null variables be done at the $var=$_POST ['var'] stage. This would clean up the inside of the sql query

Comment: What's the error produced? I can't reproduce it here: https://eval.in/561846

But yes, you can remove NULL variables at that stage. Technically, if your POST variables are something like `game_1`, then you don't even have to start setting `$Game1` variables - you can access the `$_REQUEST` array directly.